# JSON google geocode API get country

Tags: javascript, json, google-geocoding-api

I have a JSON: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=49,19&sensor=false

and I need get only short_name of country. (For this example 'SK').
Therefore I get the short_name which the attribute "types" contains [ "country", "political" ].

I have...

```
 data.results[0].address_components
```

thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This will loop through the address components and look for the country type then political. If you only want the country to be returned if both appear then let me know. Although its not hard to modify this code as the main helping point was the `for` loop.

```
// extract country short name (e.g. GB for Great Britain) from google geocode API result
function getCountry(addrComponents) {
    for (var i = 0; i < addrComponents.length; i++) {
        if (addrComponents[i].types[0] == "country") {
            return addrComponents[i].short_name;
        }
        if (addrComponents[i].types.length == 2) {
            if (addrComponents[i].types[0] == "political") {
                return addrComponents[i].short_name;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(getCountry(data.results[0].address_components));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$address = '77-379 North End road, London London SW61NP, United Kingdom'; // Your address(Please USe exist address)
$prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);

$geocode=file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&key=API_KEY&sensor=false');
$output= json_decode($geocode);


if ( isset($output->results) ) {
    if ( isset($output->results[0]) ) {
        if ( isset($output->results[0]->address_components) ) {
            foreach ($output->results[0]->address_components as $key => $value) {   
                if ( isset($value->types) ) {
                    if ( isset($value->types[0]) ) {
                        if($value->types[0] == 'country'){
                            print_r($value->short_name); //GB
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: You should add some context to your answer so readers may understand better, instead of just the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This one is to look for the address, city name, and Province

**200 Dufferin St, Toronto, ON**

```
geocoder.geocode(function (responses) {
    res = responses[0].address_components[0].short_name.concat(' ')
        .concat(responses[0].address_components[1].short_name).concat(', ')

    for (var i = 0; i < responses[0].address_components.length; i++) {
        if (responses[0].address_components[i].types[0] == "locality") {
            res = res.concat(responses[0].address_components[i].short_name).concat(', ');
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < responses[0].address_components.length; i++) {
        if (responses[0].address_components[i].types[0] == "administrative_area_level_1") {
            res = res.concat(responses[0].address_components[i].short_name);
        }
    }
    alert(res);
});
```